# Could not load type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MultiSelector' from assembly PresentationFramework

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I'm trying to use the Grid from WPFToolkit, but I'm getting the error:

```
DisplayDataMapping.xaml (9,89):
    errorMC1000: Unknown build error, 
    'Could not load type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MultiSelector' from assembly 
    'PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Line 9 Position 89.'
```

Here is the xaml:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="DisplayDataMapping"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5" BorderBrush="WhiteSmoke">
                <toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="dataGridPostings" Background="Transparent"
                            AlternatingRowBackground="LightSteelBlue"  RowBackground="White" 
                            GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="SlateGray">
                </toolkit:DataGrid>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

Comment: This may be related to a dependency on SP1 of the .NET 3.5 framework.

The build machine that this error is occurring on only has .NET 3.5, without SP1...

Answer (score 2):

The WPF Toolkit is dependent on .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (just in case you don't know already).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install VS08 SP1